# Alternative routers to the Cisco SA 500

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-vpn

We are evaluating the [Cisco SA 500 router](http://www.cisco.com/cisco/web/solutions/small_business/products/security/SA_500/index.html?Referring_site=PrintTv&Country_Site=us&Campaign=sa500&Position=Vanity&Creative=go/sa500&Where=go/sa500) for our new office router. Would anyone recommend another similarly-featured router from another manufacturer?

Requirements:
 - Office of 14 people
 - We are likely to switch to 14 VOIP phones (Linksys SPA-942) soon
 - We want to use VPN on the router, if possible, with Windows and Mac users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd second the Juniper recommendation, however the SSG line is slowly being EOL'd.

Instead look at the SRX line, SRX100 or SRX240 being the most obvious models.

Answer (score 1):

Juniper has some similar products.  I would use the [SSG 20](http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/security/ssg-series/ssg20/) as a starting point:  http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/security/ssg-series/ssg20/